# setting custom domain for a heroku app

Tags: networking, heroku, dns

tried some configs and nothing worked.
my app sits here:

https://perfect-gift.herokuapp.com/

works.

I want http://www.perfectgift.pw/ to redirect there.

getting [image: no such app]

here is my heroku settings:

[image: heroku settings]

my namecheap settings are :

[image: namecheap settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure you need to also add www.perfectgift.pw as a domain in your heroku settings. Good luck!